# Click on element inside list item does not work - VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have this Vue template, where I have added a click listener on an icon inside a list item. It works when added on parent list item but it does not work on icon element.

```
<template>
    <div class="dashboard-container">
        <md-drawer md-permanent="full">
            <md-list>
                <md-list-item class="header">
                    Groups <md-icon class="add-btn" @click="log()">add</md-icon>
                </md-list-item>
            </md-list>
        </md-drawer>
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Dashboard',
        methods: {
            log: function () {
                console.log('add')
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: can you add working code on codepen or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My assumption here is that you are using Vue Material and the problem you are mentioning is about the usage of the [MdIcon component](https://vuematerial.io/components/icon).

A viable solution is to:

- wrap the `<md-icon>` in an anchor tag;
- bind the `@click` directive on the anchor itself.

For example, like this:

```
<a href="#" @click="log()"><md-icon class="add-btn">add</md-icon></a>
```

Here it is a [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PggRLy) where the `log` method properly fires at `onClick` event because of the wrapping.